# How to embed model version or description within a tensorflow lite model file (v 1.x)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way for us to embed some text description like model version number etc into a tensorflow lite model prior to using the model on mobile devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the metadata field:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/schema/schema.fbs#L903

Comment: This suggests modifying the tf sourcecode. I don't see any API in Python, at least, to be able to do this while converting a model into tflite.